# Possibility to use Python 3.6 with Intel MKL 2017 and a Xeon Phi KNC Card

Tags: python, xeon-phi, intel-python

I am experimenting with an Intel Xeon Phi 3120A card and automatic offloading using Python. I got it running using Intel Python 2017 with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858787/automatic-offloading-with-intel-python-2019-and-xeon-phi-knc) post. By that I found out that the card unfortunately is only supported by the 2017 version of MKL for automatic offloading. As Intel Python 2017 is based on Python 3.5 I am wondering if there is some way to use, e.g., Python 3.6 with MKL 2017 to preserve the automatic offloading functionality of the Xeon Phi card. Can I somehow set up a Miniconda environment with Python 3.6 still using MKL 2017? Or is it possible to compile numpy and scipy with the old MKL library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build scipy and numpy from source while linking it against MKL BLAS and MKL LAPACK.
Use this to get you started: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/building.html